# How to migrate .trn files into azure databases?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I am receiving multiple .trn files on daily basis & I am resorting those file in on-premises sql database. Now How we can migrate those .trn files daily on azure.

Answer (score 0):

Connect on-premises SQL database to Azure data factory using Self hosted IR. A self-hosted integration runtime can run **copy activities between a cloud data store and a data store in a private network.**

Create pipeline and use copy activity.

Select on-premises SQL database as Source.

Select Azure service of your choice as Sink.

Now use trigger to copy data from on premise to Azure periodically.

Refer – Copy activity [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview)

Also refer – Trigger [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger?tabs=data-factory)

Comment: Hi Abhishek we can do this things when we have data in on-premises database but the thing is how we can load data from .trn files to Azure